# POST request not working on WAMP

Tags: php, request, http-post, wamp, android-volley

I create a web service with php which is using POST method to getting parameters from android application. I m using VOLLEY to send request to server.

i want to use wamp server to communicate with app

but when i send POST request from app to wamp server, nothing happen.

i add port 80 and 8080 to inbound firewall

but still getting nothing...

what should i do to use wamp server as a real server?

please help me to find this problem

how to configure wamp and apache to solve this issue

Comment: There is in no way nearly enough information to say what is going on. It seems like you are just guessing what *might* go wrong instead of actually researching what it is you need to fix.

Answer (score -1):

The normal problem here is that by default WAMPServer's Apache is configured, for the security of beginners and because its designed to be a developer tool and not a live server, to be accessable only from the PC WAMPServer is installed on.

So first try changing this default config. Its all doable from the wampmanager menus like this

```
left click Wampmanager -> Put Online
```

This will change the `httpd.conf` file to allow access from any ip address and restart Apache so it picks up the changes

Comment: i changed it to online mode. but i didnt get any response... should i do something else? (i m using volley library in android)

Comment: What url are you using in the java code to get to the apache server? Maybe add some of the java code to your question, with an edit